# What does the _f32 suffix mean?

Tags: rust

I came across this line of code written in rust and do not understand what is happening here. Can anyone explain this line of code written in rust?

```
let decimal = 65.4321_f32;
```

What does `_f32` do?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is called as [floating point literals](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#floating-point-literals), see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/literal-expr.html) for other literal expressions

Answer (score 6):

In rust you can specify numeric types but adding a trailing tag:

```rust
0usize
0i32
0u32
0f32
0f64
...
```

Also you have the possibility of adding `_` as a visual separator in numbers, it doesn't affect the final value itself (`1_2_3` would be `123` anyway):

```rust
10
100
1000
10_000
100_000
1_000_000
...
```

By mixing both of them you arrive at the final form used in your question where the `_` is used to separate the type tag itself:

```rust
10_000.1001_f32
```

You can take a look at the [literal expressions documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/literal-expr.html)

Answer (score 4):

It declares the type as a 32-bit float.  There is a brief discussion [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15142457).  The "_" is just semantic sugar, separating the value from the type.